# How to byte-compile a file in the background?

Tags: buffers, byte-compilation, tangle

To cut time on untangling my org setup file, I now only compile on save.
However it is somewhat annoying to have the compile buffer popup on every save.

```
  ;; Only untangle on a change/save
  (defun my/tangle-dotfiles ()
    "If the current file is this file, the code blocks are tangled"
    (interactive)
    (when (equal (buffer-file-name) (file-truename (expand-file-name "myinit.org" user-emacs-directory)))
      (org-babel-tangle-file (expand-file-name "myinit.org" user-emacs-directory)
                             (expand-file-name "myinit.el" user-emacs-directory)
                             )
      (byte-compile-file (expand-file-name "myinit.el" user-emacs-directory))
      )
    )
  (add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my/tangle-dotfiles)
```

Is there a way to have this statement:

```
(byte-compile-file (expand-file-name "myinit.el" user-emacs-directory))
```

Run in the background instead in a buffer that pops up every time I save?

Comment: How about running a batch separate Emacs instance for the sole purpose of byte-compiling your file?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html

Answer (score 1):

Byte-compiling is a CPU-bound activity, unlike with subprocesses and network processes there is no way of doing it asynchronously in the same Emacs instance.  What you can do though is launching an Emacs subprocess and making it byte-compile the file.  [async.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) offers support for this, try `async-byte-compile-file` from `async-bytecomp.el`.